# How to add a method to delete a object from the bucket?

Tags: javascript, node.js, autodesk-viewer

I want to create a method to remove already uploaded objects from the buckets. There is a method for uploading objects into the bucket, but there is no method for deleting them. Tell me how to do this?

I do it for the viewer autodesk Forge, the sources of which downloaded from [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewmodels/tree/nodejs).

I tried to make it myself, but I failed. There were no changes to the downloaded sources, but in any case I can show my unsuccessful code.

```js
// POST /api/forge/oss/buckets - delete file.
router.post('/objects', multer({ dest: 'delete/' }).single('fileToDelete'), async (req, res, next) => {
  fs.readFile(req.file.path, async (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      next(err);
    }
    try {
      // Upload an object to bucket using [ObjectsApi](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/docs/ObjectsApi.md#uploadObject).
      await new ObjectsApi().deleteObject(req.body.bucketKey, req.file.originalname);
      res.status(200).end();
    } catch(err) {
      next(err);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
  <form id="upLoadFile" method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="hiddenUploadFiled" type="file" name="theFile" style="visibility:hidden" />
  </form>
```

I expect that there is a way to add a method to remove loaded objects from a from bucket.

Comment: Not a solution, but you really should use 'delete' and not 'post'

Comment: I tried it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pass in your oauth credentials as well:

```
 objectsApi.deleteObject(bucketKey,fileName,oAuth2TwoLegged, oAuth2TwoLegged.getCredentials());
```

See usage doc for the `deleteObject` [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/docs/ObjectsApi.md#uploadObject) and code sample [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-nodejs-client/blob/10ed8a418e62d1e83036ba866ca5aadd0e38de34/samples/dmSample.js#L119)

And when you said you downloaded the source code it’d make things a lot easier for you if you can install our latest Forge Node client SDK via NPM and import required modules into your project. See instructions [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Bryan Huang, thank you very much. But I have a question, I use axios, how can I add some models to the viewer?

Comment: With axios simply use the DELETE verb to call our endpoint such as `axios.delete('https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/yourBucketName/objects/yourObjectName', {'authorization':   'Bearer yourAccessToken'})`. Can see doc in my answer for API details.